# Create and edit MariaDB procedures with the same user but in distint machine

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb, privileges

I have created some procedures in MariaDB, sometimes using MySQL Workbench and sometimes Adminer, from my personal notebook. The server is in a site managed with cPanel.

Now, when I wanted to edit the procedures from my workplace PC, I discovered that it is impossible, in fact I can't even see them. And conversely it is the same, the procedures created in my office I can not edit them in my house.

It seems that MariaDB is very strict when comparing the creator user, which differs in the address of the machine where I work, eg in my notebook is myUser@120.120.120 while in my PC it is myUser@230.230.230.

Is there a method for a user to create and edit procedures on different devices? It must be considered that it is absolutely impossible that they grant me SUPER privileges.

Comment: What version of MariaDB?  Any authentication plugin?

Comment: SSH to work?....